# Failing to retrieve access token in .NET desktop app

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-authentication

I'm writing a .NET app that runs on a Windows computer. It is not accessible through the browser. The problem is, I can't authenticate like I should. I'm currently coding in C# .NET, more specific in C#.

- I have a webbrowser control on my form.
- The user logs on to facebook through this webbrowser control.
- After the logon, I start the authentication procedure.
- I then retreive a code.

Here's where it goes wrong. With this code I want to obtain an access token.
The generated request URL looks like: `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=____MY_APP_ID______&redirect_uri=http://localhost/&client_secret=_____MY_APP_SECRET_____&code=____MY_RETREIVED_CODE_____` and is made through the code below.

Please note that my redirect URL is `http://localhost`. This should be okay, right?

Also, in my App Settings, I have the following information.

> Site URL: `http://localhost/`
>   Site Domain: localhost

```
private String ExchangeCodeForToken(String code, Uri redirectUrl)
{
    var TokenEndpoint = new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token");
    var url = TokenEndpoint + "?" +
                      "client_id=" + _AppID + "&" +
                      "redirect_uri=" + redirectUrl + "&" +
                      "client_secret=" + _AppSecret + "&" +
                      "code=" + code;
    var request = WebRequest.CreateDefault(new Uri(url));
    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (var responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                var responseText = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                var token = responseText.Replace("access_token=", "");
                return token;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

When I execute this, I get this error:

[error http://www.imageupload.org/getfile.php?id=50131&a=447f6fcc0ebd4d3f8e8a59a3a6e36ac3&t=4de0841c&o=0889D68FDC35508BA2C6F2689FCBAB7C30A8670CC9647EE598701D8BEC13ED278F0989D393&n=autherror.png&i=1](http://www.imageupload.org/getfile.php?id=50131&a=447f6fcc0ebd4d3f8e8a59a3a6e36ac3&t=4de0841c&o=0889D68FDC35508BA2C6F2689FCBAB7C30A8670CC9647EE598701D8BEC13ED278F0989D393&n=autherror.png&i=1)

> Webexception was unhandled by user code
>   The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Here's where I think I might be going wrong:

- Are my app settings correct?
- Should my redirect url be `http://localhost`, even if there isn't actually a service listening there?

Most importantly:

- how do I get rid of this error and retreive the access token?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You get this error because you are not supposed to call this URL from a Desktop app : as far as I know, you can not use the token endpoint for Desktop app authentication. Also, you can get the access token directly (no need to ask for a code first). Here is what you have to do.

Load the following URL in your embedded web browser :

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
  client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&
  redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
```

The user will be asked to log in and will be redirected to this URL with the access token in the URL :

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=...
```

So you have to detect the redirect and retrieve the access token from the URL.

Comment: Thanks a million! I had the exact same issue. But how would you do that, if my app runs on a terminal? I surely, cant have a proper browser.

More details: I am building a KDE-Plasmoid to post statuses to Facebook account. I cant have an embedded browser also. I am using Python. Best shot at having a browser is using Mechanize module, if that helps.. :-)

Comment: Hi Thrustmaster. Due to the oauth flow and for security reasons, there is no way for you to have a user logged in Facebook without a browser... You can try to make a hack by simulating the browser by dealing with HTTP requests in Python, but I am not sure about that. And you will be asking the username and password of your users, which violates the Terms of Service of Facebook.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But even in the embedded browser, I(Facebook) will be asking for username/password. If its my browser, I can very well retrieve the username and password, and that too without the knowledge of user.

Comment: If you use an embedded browser, you would not have in your hands the user's credentials because he will be typing them right into Facebook website (except of course if you listen to the keystrokes). Anyway, the end user will not know if you listen to his credentials or not, he is trusting the developer, you can do whatever you want. It is not that you **can not**, it is that you **should not**. And Facebook will not make your life easier if you choose to do it (no librairies, no documentation, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. :-)
I am opening a new question, aiming at my problem.

Comment: And I am going to track that question because I am interested in hearing about it :)

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162063/facebook-authentication-for-desktop-console-based-application/6162444 :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks quinten!

However, I've managed to solve my own problem by using the C# Facebook SDK.
This software development kit has been a really great help!

There are a lot of samples included (including authorisation)

Anyone who programs in .NET with facebook should check it out! Coding for facebook is now much easier.

http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/