# Facebook Authentication for Desktop (Console based) application

Tags: python, facebook, oauth

I am working on a python application which allows me to post updates/statuses to Facebook.

I am facing a basic problem with getting access tokens.

Since this application is working on the desktop, there is no question of using some web server.

I understand that I have to open a URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
```

..and get the tokens out of the redirected URL.

But even this is out of option, since mine is a console based application. The closest I can get to using embedded browser is by using Python's `mechanize` module.

Is there any other option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can have some setup process where you obtain the tokens with offline access, that way the user will need to be presented with facebook login page only once, then you use this token later with the console app.

See offline_access on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Comment: Yes, I know about offline access. The tokens are received as a part of URL after the user and given the access. For that purpose, we need a full-fledged GUI browser, which is too much for a simple python console application. Is there any way, as simple as twitter provides us with?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/)?

> PhantomJS is a command-line tool that packs and embeds WebKit. Literally it acts like any other WebKit-based web browser, except that nothing gets displayed to the screen (thus, the term headless). In addition to that, PhantomJS can be controlled or scripted using its JavaScript API.